# How to plan a trajectory having path in the form (x_i,y_i,theta_i), robot FK and Invers Kinematic and constraints?

Tags: matlab, robotics

I have the following information:
1.Inital path for the robot from start state to goal state in the form (x_i,y_i,theta_i),
2. Robot forward and inverse kinematics,
3. Some constraints to be posed on the robot related to velocity and acceleration.

I want to know how to utilize those known inputs to plan a trajectory then execute it by commanding robot to follow the produced trajectory.

I have done many searches but I still find it confusing, some utilized smoothing algorithms, other used optimization method so on so forth.